# Pupetteer selector for ancestor of matched element?

Tags: xpath, automation, css-selectors, puppeteer

There is limited documentation on how to use and combine Pupetteer "p-selectors" (such as `::-p-text` and `::-p-xpath`) inside larger selectors which can be evaluated using the `.waitForSelector()` method.

My goal is to select the `div` parent containing `svg[attr="value1"]` from the `anchor` element which contains a `span` (anywhere) with an inner text that matches "I Know This Text"

```html
  <div>
  <a>
    <div>
      <span>I Know This Text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div> <!-- I want this div -->
        <svg data-key="value1"></svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <svg data-key="value2"></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>...</a>
  <a>...</a>
  <a>...</a>
</div>
```

**How can these all be combined using a single selector from the page or an element?**

```js
let desiredDiv = await pageOrElementHandle.waitForSelector('?"I Know This Text"?')

await desiredDiv?.click()
```

I know I can break this up into multiple steps, alternating repeatedly between `.waitForSelector()` and `.getProperty('parentElement')` but I am *very tired* of relying this because I only get direct parents, and there is no way to get a specific parent or ancestor with attributes. **Am I missing knowledge of how to traverse up and down nested elements using puppeteer selectors that can be evaluated using `.waitForSelector()` method?**

I would just use `page.x$(xpathSelector)` but, in my code base, I need to query element handles (that are *returned from* `page.waitForSelector()`), which do not support `.x$()` but do support `.waitForSelector()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood your task correct, xpath of your `div` is
`//a[.//span[text()='I Know This Text']]//div[./*[@data-key='value1']]`

But this is not good practice.
I suggest to search it in code itself.

For example, you can achieve this by using my puppeteer wrapper library https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai

[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html)

Example of code

```js
import { getElements, getText, filterAsync, waitForScopedSelector, getParent } from 'bubanai-ng'

const elements = await getElements(page, 'a');
    const filterFunc = (element: ElementHandle) =>
      element
        .$('span')
        .then(
          (e) =>
            !!e &&
            getText(page, e).then((t) => t === 'I Know This Text'),
        );
const anchor = await filterAsync(elements, filterFunc);
const result = await waitForScopedSelector(
      page,
      anchor[0],
      '[data-key=value1]',
    ).then((el) => getParent(page, el));
```

This code is a bit maintainable than complicated xpath selector.

(Btw, each method from library can use css or xpath selectors or ElementHandle)

Comment: Yes, that is a good xpath, but I want to know how to use it in puppeteer waitForSelector() call. I will only use this huge app for a few months, so I prefer to keep the concise xpath vs verbose/maintainable code.

Comment: @NicoWheat what version of Puppeteer do you use? If you have ElementHandle , newest versions supports waitForXpath from ElementHandle.

AFAIK waitForSelector can't support xpath, but you can write your own wrapper that accepts both xpath or css selectors and don't care if future, which type of selector you pass inside. 

Like 

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/src/element/waits/waitForScopedSelector.ts

where

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/src/element/types.ts#L72

Comment: @NicoWheat btw, I found interesting thing in their documentation.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/src/api/ElementHandle.ts#L586

Try `xpath/${xpath}`

Comment: But probably mentioned above syntax wouldn't work on old Puppeteer versions.
For older versions waitFor works for me both for css / xpath, but this method is deprecated, so I suggest to avoid it.

    `const element = await page.waitFor("//*[@id='myElement']").then((r) => r && r.asElement());`